# Interpreting XDL / Deadlock dumps in SSMS

Tags: ssms, deadlock, azure-sql-database

I've generated the following XML + XDL: 
[image]

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="processc1eaf13468" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="processc1eaf13468" taskpriority="0" logused="892" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594044547072 (c9fb1da9313f)" waittime="5244" ownerId="118489" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-06-27T15:17:20.250" XDES="0xc1e878c4c0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="144900" status="suspended" spid="119" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-06-27T15:20:22.437" lastbatchcompleted="2017-06-27T15:17:21.003" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.003" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="MIKBEN-W530" hostpid="30520" loginname="HuddleFm" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="118489" currentdb="11" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x05ff9bdd8b808318" queryplanhash="0x5cc8b281eb7808cd" line="1" stmtstart="256" stmtend="970" sqlhandle="0x020000005f1e5a01ca72346b429f4c909878692fbda9bbd20000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@0 nvarchar(512),@1 int,@2 int,@3 bigint,@4 int,@5 int,@6 int,@7 datetime2(7),@8 int,@9 int,@10 bit,@11 bit,@12 nvarchar(max) )INSERT [dbo].[AppEvent]([MediaPath], [StorageProvider], [MediaType], [MediaSizeInBytes], [OldSessionState], [NewSessionState], [AppEventType], [EventDate], [DeviceSessionId], [TargetSessionId], [UserId], [ShouldBeDeleted], [HasBeenDeleted], [Payload], [LocalBrowserSessionGuid])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, NULL, @9, @10, @11, NULL, @12)
SELECT [AppEventId]
FROM [dbo].[AppEvent]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT &gt; 0 AND [AppEventId] = scope_identity()   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="processc1e7c26ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="1064" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594043170816 (40fd182c0dd9)" waittime="5396" ownerId="118496" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-06-27T15:17:20.890" XDES="0xc1e88b44c0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="194344" status="suspended" spid="123" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-06-27T15:20:22.283" lastbatchcompleted="2017-06-27T15:17:21.060" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.060" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="MIKBEN-W530" hostpid="30520" loginname="HuddleFm" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="118496" currentdb="11" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0xebf55cdceee65c9c" queryplanhash="0x5cc8b281eb7808cd" line="1" stmtstart="220" stmtend="936" sqlhandle="0x0200000066a736157a1b98ec891323511cd809b8ea3bf4a30000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@0 int,@1 int,@2 bigint,@3 int,@4 int,@5 int,@6 datetime2(7),@7 int,@8 int,@9 bit,@10 bit,@11 nvarchar(max) )INSERT [dbo].[AppEvent]([MediaPath], [StorageProvider], [MediaType], [MediaSizeInBytes], [OldSessionState], [NewSessionState], [AppEventType], [EventDate], [DeviceSessionId], [TargetSessionId], [UserId], [ShouldBeDeleted], [HasBeenDeleted], [Payload], [LocalBrowserSessionGuid])
VALUES (NULL, @0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, NULL, @8, @9, @10, NULL, @11)
SELECT [AppEventId]
FROM [dbo].[AppEvent]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT &gt; 0 AND [AppEventId] = scope_identity()   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594044547072" dbid="11" objectname="e6288089-3180-4261-aa4e-916673f3cd8a.dbo.DeviceSession" indexname="PK_dbo.DeviceSession" id="lockc1f1b6b300" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594044547072">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processc1e7c26ca8" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processc1eaf13468" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594043170816" dbid="11" objectname="e6288089-3180-4261-aa4e-916673f3cd8a.dbo.User" indexname="PK_dbo.User" id="lockc1f1b6c280" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594043170816">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processc1eaf13468" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processc1e7c26ca8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

I'm now trying to understand what's causing the deadlock; I've never interpreted this kind of log before.  I see that there is some contention between `User` and `DeviceSession` but I'm not sure where that's coming from.  How does one go about interpreting an XDL / Deadlock dump?

Comment: By using SQL Profiler we can obtain the deadlock graph. You can use the standard TSQL_Locks template. The event that we are interested in is the Deadlock Graph.  Check this link: https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-graphical-representation-sql-server-deadlock-graph/

Comment: @CR241 I don't have access to the profiler because this is SQL Azure.

Comment: @SB2055 I will highly recommend reading [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2006/09/08/deadlock-troubleshooting-part-1/) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2006/09/12/deadlock-troubleshooting-part-2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few resources for you to start with.

1. [Detecting and Ending Deadlocks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx)
2. [Deadlock Troubleshooting, Part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2006/09/08/deadlock-troubleshooting-part-1/)
3. [Deadlock Troubleshooting, Part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2006/09/12/deadlock-troubleshooting-part-2/)
4. [SQL Server Deadlocks by Example](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/sql-server-deadlocks-by-example/)

In your case, session 123 is holding an exclusive key lock on `PK_dbo.DeviceSession` and waiting for a shared key lock on object `PK_dbo.User`.

Victim session 119 has the opposite. It's holding an exclusive key lock on `PK_dbo.User` and  waiting for a shared key lock on object `PK_dbo.DeviceSession`.

This caused a circular blocking chain and SQL Server has to choose one as a victim.

How do you solve deadlock issues? It is a subject that needs a lot of effort to master. I suggest starting [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/the-accidental-dba-day-29-of-30-troubleshooting-deadlocks/).